# How to change favicon in sails?

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I am a new for sails framework. I want to change a favicon so I replace my favicon file in the

```
myproject/assets/favicon.ico
```

But it's still old favicon.

How should I do to change it.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried doing a force refresh? http://superuser.com/questions/220179/how-can-i-do-a-cache-refresh-in-google-chrome

Comment: I search in folder and I found the old favicon in "\node_modules\sails\node_modules\skipper\node_modules\connect\lib\public" and "\node_modules\sails\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\public"

I've already replace both but it's still not working.

Comment: Okay, I cleared cached images and files. It works now.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try force refreshing the browser.

```
command + shift + r
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure the new favicon is in ".ico" format - some image editors can open and edit an .ico file but automatically save it as a .png or other non-icon formats.  Renaming it back to .ico should resolve the issue.